# Generic notification framework/API

Tags: notifications

I'm looking for a specific functionality/piece of software, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me find it.

I administer a fairly large number of servers and run some long-term jobs on some of them (system ones, php, bash, perl scripts, etc)

I'm looking for something like a cross between libnotify (in that it uses DBUS/programmes hook into it and there's a notification daemon), and google's re-imagined unified notification system.

Ideally it wouldn't require re-writing everything and would intercept notifications (even on headless servers) and then handle them per a user's configuration options. These would probably be sent to some centralised location and dispatched to email/chat/text message/libnotify popup.

Bonus points if it handles the case for

- If I'm listed as "available" on a certain computer, it'll send notifications there, and email
- Otherwise it will failover down a list of `write`ing to my logged in terminals on that computer (like broadcast shutdown messages), IMing me, text mesasging me.
- All will send an email just in case.

Comment: Did you find such a framework/API? I'm looking for a way to receive/show notification on a headless machine.